# Correspondence between fellerian markov processes and contractive semigroups

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

The following passage is from Petr Mandl's book An Analytical treatment of one-dimensional Markov processes. pg 37

[image]

If we begin with a Fellerian process, then its induced semigroup is a strongly continuous contractive semigroup.

[image]

Conversely, if we begin with a strongly continuous contractive semigroup we can generate (via Kolmogorov extension theorem on cartesian spaces) a Fellerian Markov process.

This is in contrast with what is beeing said in the book, since Mandl says that there is a one to one correspondence between Fellerian markov processes and contractive semigroups in $C_I$?

Is that a typo from the author?

Moreover, if we start with a probability transition semigroup this is not a sufficient condition for the procees to be fellerian. Therefore a question that arises is:

Is there a one to one correspondence between Markov processes (not necessarily fellerian) and contractive semigroups (not necessarily strongly continuous)